# How to add var javascript in appendTo?

Tags: javascript

How to add var javascript in appendTo ?

```
var i = 1;
$('<input type="text" id="num" size="20" name="num[]"/>').appendTo(scntDiv);
```

How to add `var i` into `id="num"` to `id="num_1"`

Comment: Don't build HTML as strings.

Comment: @ torazaburo - could you please give me some advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append `i` into your generated HTML:

```
$('<input type="text" id="num_' + i + '" size="20" name="num[]"/>').appendTo(scntDiv);
```